# Поиск по сайту

Tags: c#

Как сделать поиск по сайту так, чтоб программа автоматически открывала и переходила по ссылкам?

Comment: А по подробней что надо?

Comment: подробней чтобы прога открывала в автомате ссылки находящиеся на странице и сохраняла их HTML))

Comment: в каком автомате нужно?

Comment: прога типа паука преходила по ссылкам на странице открывала ссылку, сохраняла HTML код и переходила к следующей ссылке!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете использовать любой язык программирования и API, которое позволяет работать с сокетами. Создавайте GET-запросы, получайте от сервера страницы, разбирайте их, отыскивайте ссылки, посылайте по ним новые запросы.

Для большинства языков вы можете найти готовые библиотечки которые часть забот возьмут на себя - создание запросов или парсинг HTML например. Однако как бороться с циклическими ссылками - это вам уж придётся думать самостоятельно.

Извините что ответ не очень конкретен - но уж каков вопрос... ;-)